# Using the memory management in objective C correctly

Tags: objective-c

I'm using a low level API for the first time in Objc and now  I have to control the memory management more then I would have on the higher level apis. So I read the advanced and basic memory management guides written by Apple. But now in practice I'm not 100% sure so I made a small example to see if this is the way to go. My code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        [super drawRect:rect];

        //Method contains the word "Get" so make sure it won't release so retain it
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextRetain(context);

        //No retain needed since method contains word "Create"
        CFStringRef string = CFStringCreateWithCString(kCFAllocatorDefault, "Supppp....", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
        CFShowStr(string);
        CFRelease(string);

        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 6.0);
        CGContextStrokeRoundedRect(context, CGRectInset(rect, 5 , 5), 3);

        //Clean up
        CGContextRelease(context);
    }

void CGContextRoundedRect(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGFloat radius, CGPathDrawingMode mode) {
        CGFloat minx = CGRectGetMinX(rect), midx = CGRectGetMidX(rect), maxx = CGRectGetMaxX(rect);
        CGFloat miny = CGRectGetMinY(rect), midy = CGRectGetMidY(rect), maxy = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);
        CGContextRetain(context);

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minx, midy);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, miny, midx, miny, radius);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, miny, maxx, midy, radius);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxx, maxy, midx, maxy, radius);
        CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minx, maxy, minx, midy, radius);
        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextDrawPath(context, mode);

        //Cleanup
        CGContextRelease(context);
    }

    void CGContextFillRoundedRect(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGFloat radius) {
        CGContextRetain(context);
        CGContextRoundedRect(context, rect, radius, kCGPathFill);
        CGContextRelease(context);
    }

void CGContextStrokeRoundedRect(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGFloat radius) {
        CGContextRetain(context);
        CGContextRoundedRect(context, rect, radius, kCGPathStroke);
        CGContextRelease(context);
    }
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me. Just keep in mind the retain count. In this case you're decrementing whenever you increment. Although since these references are being passed in why do you need to retain any of them?

Comment: @Literphor I'm not sure I thought that I had to retain in for example CGContextRoundedRect to make sure that the context won't be released before this method is done. Or is this not needed?

Comment: Someone more experienced than me will have to verify but I believe that's only a worry if that object can be released somewhere in your app asynchronously. That would be kind of odd I think. Retaining is something you do to increase an object's lifetime. By retaining, you're saying that object now has ownership and the retained object will not be deallocated until all objects that have ownership call release on it, that is, it won't deallocate until its retain count is 0.

Comment: @Literphor Ok, so I think it is safe to retain in those method because it just makes sure if stuff happen async (which probably won't happen in this case, but hey lets learn it the right way) I won't run into a crash.